# Solo mining before wallet got sync'd

Tags: wallet, synchronization, solo-mining

So the question is can i start mining(solo)/using my wallet for transactions or whatever when my wallet is not sync'd? I've tried to mine solo but it doesn't work =(.

Comment: What have you tried? How is it failing?  It is possible to mine and sync at the same time. Some hints: Bitcoin client needs to run in server mode for one thing.  Also what mining software are you using?

Comment: I've tried exactly solo minining in server mode with bitcoin-qt(launchs from .bat file "bitcoin-qt -server -datadir:=Disk\folder(example)") client and 50miner; file Bitcoin.conf is also created. I would be very greatful if you help me. We can contact by email or something else so i'll be able to describe anything you might need to know if you know much about this and ready to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solo mine if you're not synched. In order to mine, you need to know what the longest chain is, and you can't do that until you're synched.

Comment: O, it does make sense, thank you. That's exactly what i needed to know.